# I have a question I have been trying on LeetCode and needed help in the error which is Time Limit exceeded

Tags: c++, binary-search

The link to the particular question is as follows: https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-magical-number/. My code is showing "Time Limit Exceeded" and I cannot figure out where actually lies the error in my code. My code is as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    typedef unsigned int ull;
    int gcd(int A,int B)
    {
        if(B==0)
            return A;
        else
            return gcd(B,A%B);
    }
    int nthMagicalNumber(int N, int A, int B) {
        ull m;
        if(A<B)
        {
           int t;
            t=A;
            A=B;
            B=t;
        }
        ull lcm=(A*B)/gcd(A,B);
        ull l=2;
        ull h=1e9;
        ull n;
        while(l<=h)
        {
            m=l+(h-1)/2;
           n=(m/A)+(m/B)-(m/lcm);
            if(n==N)
                break;
            else if(n<N)
                l=m+1;
            else if(n>N)
                h=m-1;
        }
        ull x=(1e9)+7;
        return (int)(m%x);       
    }
};
```

Can someone let me know where I am wrong and how can I correct the error?

Comment: Exceeding the time limit doesn't necessarily mean there is an error in your code. It generally means you have chosen an algorithm that is not efficient enough to solve the problem in the time required.

Comment: Time Limit exceeded almost always means your solution uses an algorithm that is not efficient enough and you'll have to find a better algorithm. Significantly less often your code may have a viable algorithm, but it accesses memory inefficiently.

Comment: See if remembering GCDs (memoization)  rather than recomputing them every time helps.

Comment: Regarding `typedef unsigned int ull;` from the name `ull` I would have expected `typedef unsigned long long ull;`. It's because of nasty surprises like this you should prefer using standard types like the ones found in `<cstdint>` ([these for example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)). They take a bit more typing, but are immediately understandable to anyone familiar with C or C++.

Comment: Is there a reason you created the class?  The functions can be free-standing.

Comment: `typedef unsigned int ull;` - Please don't obfuscate your code like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a debugger for that. This solution is just very similar (using Binary Search with gcd) and would pass through:

```
// This block might trivially optimize the exec time;
// Can be removed;

const static auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>


const static struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::uint_fast64_t;
    static constexpr SizeType kMod = 1e9 + 7;
    const SizeType nthMagicalNumber(
        const SizeType N,
        const SizeType A,
        const SizeType B
    ) {
        const SizeType lowest_common_multiple = A * B / getGreatestCommonDivisor(A, B);
        SizeType lo = 2;
        SizeType hi = 1e14;


        while (lo < hi) {
            SizeType mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

            if (mid / A + mid / B - mid / lowest_common_multiple < N) {
                lo = mid + 1;

            } else {
                hi = mid;
            }
        }

        return lo % kMod;
    }

    // __gcd(a, b)
    static const SizeType getGreatestCommonDivisor(
        const SizeType a,
        const SizeType b
    ) {
        if (not b) {
            return a;
        }

        return getGreatestCommonDivisor(b, a % b);

    }
};
```

Instead of `ull`, here we are using  `std::uint_fast64_t`.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-magical-number/) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.